# Fastest algorithm to create an array of known size

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to create an array of boolean values, which could be on the scale of 100,000s or even millions of entries.  It also needs to be super-fast, so every millisecond per iteration counts.

At the time of beginning the loop, I will already know how many entries there are going to be in the array.  The question is, will it be faster to create a bool array up front and fill in the values by index (which is random access - could be slow?), or should I create a `List<bool>`, keep adding entries to the list, and at the end return `.ToArray()`?

In other words:

**Option 1**

```
var array = new bool[size];
for (var n=0; n<size; n++)
  array[n] = GetValue(n);
return array;
```

**Option 2**

```
var list = new List<bool>();
for (var n=0; n<size; n++)
  list.Add(GetValue(n));
return list.ToArray();
```

Or maybe there's a 3rd way that's even faster?

Comment: Accessing array by index is O(1) and is probably the fastest among all data structures.

Comment: "which is random access - could be slow?" What's the line of thinking that leads you to say this? I suspect you have a false idea that's leading you astray -- maybe that `list.Add(GetValue(n));` has a chance of being faster than `array[n] = GetValue(n);` because "accessing the end" is faster than "accessing anywhere"?

Comment: @SteveJessop yes, that was my thinking, since List.Add always appends to the list, while array[n] needs to do a seek for the array position.  And thank you for disabusing me of it.  Do you have a link that explains why `List.Add` is slower?

Comment: I don't have a link to hand, but accessing `array[n]` doesn't have to do a seek. It adds an offset `n` to some pointer stored in `array`. `list.Add()` does the same, except that the offset it uses is the current size of the list (stored in `list`) minus one. And `Add` may need to do some extra housekeeping, such as updating the size of the list at each step, and occasionally allocating new space. I say "may", because the optimizer might be able to deal with some of it. There's one potential overhead of `array[n]` that `Add` doesn't need, the bounds check on `n`. Again the JIT might remove it.

Comment: Now this is [how learning assembly aids in programming](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156722/how-does-learning-assembly-aid-in-programming).

Comment: @GSerg - check out my answer below

Comment: @SteveJessop - check out my answer below.

Comment: `List` is implemented using an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code seems to show (at least to me) that of the methods discussed on this page, the simple allocation to a `bool[]` using a loop is quickest.

The code also seems to show me that unless `GetValue(n)` is computationally trivial, the overhead of allocating the bytes is not the part of the process I would be hoping to optimise.

Hope this helps in some way.

edit: added the results from the run (on my machine)

```
--  187ms    BitArray
--  171ms    List<bool>().ToArray 
--  168ms    bool[] set only if true
--  130ms    bool[] always set
--11460ms    bool[] always set with 'complex' GetValue()

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(10000000);
        bool[] boolArray = new bool[10000000];

        Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();

        sw1.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            bitArray[i] = GetMod2(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw1.Restart();

        var list = new List<bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            list.Add(GetMod2(i));
        var boolArray2 = list.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw1.Restart();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            bool nextVal = GetMod2(i);

            if (nextVal)
                bitArray[i] = true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw1.Restart();


        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            boolArray[i] = GetMod2(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw1.Restart();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            boolArray[i] = GetRand(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool GetMod2(int i)
    {
        return (i % 2) == 1;
    }

    static bool GetRand(int i)
    {
        return new Random().Next(2) == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks!  Seems obvious in retrospect to do a benchmark test like this...

Comment: Your results don't look right.  How can setting every element in the `bool[]` be faster than only setting the `true` values?

Comment: are you saying that you do not expect the results you are seeing, or that the code doesn't look right?

Comment: I would not expect those results.  But I think I can see why - because you're doing a variable assignment and then entering the conditional.  If you just said `if (GetMod2(i))...` you would probably find it faster.  But in any case, as you commented, this is probably not the area where optimization will have the biggest payback - `GetValue()` will be much more significant in determining the return time.

Comment: Answer credit for suggesting doing the benchmarking, and especially for noting that the real performance boost will come from optimizing `GetValue()` rather than the array creation.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`System.Collections.BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) and don't worry about speed.

What you are suggesting above will only waste your memory. This is optimizes both for speed and size, and will pack your `bool` values nicely (8 per byte, as the gods intended :).

Reply to below comments: If you use a `BitArray`, everything will be zero at first. Set only those bits for which you have `GetValue == true`.

Comment: Programming is always about a compromise between memory consumption and execution speed. The OP seems to want the speed.

Comment: Sure he wants.  The speed he will get, at least 8 times more, probably even faster, since runtime will use everything it can to zero out block of memory for him.

Comment: But surely zeroing out does not matter? He allocates an array, then initializes each element with a result of a function.

Comment: Responding to the edit: I see your intended point, but surely `if (GetValue(n)) array[n] = GetValue(n)` is slower than `array[n] = GetValue(n)`? Even if you introduce a temp variable for the `GetValue` result.

Comment: The result has to be a bool array, since I'm returning it to a non-CLR client that doesn't understand CLR objects like BitArray.  Do you think it'll still be faster if I have to add the step of `.CopyTo()` at the end?

Comment: @Shaul No, it won't. Read Steve's comments to your question. It really helps if you understand what's happening under the hood, what is a pointer, how a pointer is dereferenced and what is a pointer offset. It might help to get a little C++ tour.

Comment: Well +1 anyway for noting that I only need to set the value to true for those indexes where `GetValue(n)` is true.

Comment: Well, if you said that array<bool> is expected somewhere else, I wouldn't suggest bitarray at all.  Glad you did your own benchmarks...

Answer (score 2):

Go with the first. The only reason it might be.    "slow" is if it keeps paging data from outside the processor cache.

The list will have exactly the same problem, except it will also need to perform several memory allocations and copies.

Answer (score 0):

Now here's a funny old thing.  Inspired by @paul, I ran these benchmark tests myself, on 10,000,000 booleans.  The results (in milliseconds) are very surprising, given the discussion in the comments to this question:

> BitArray: 517
>
> BitArray + CopyTo(array): 536
>
> List + ToArray(): 455
>
> bool array: 483

And what a turnout for the books!  Despite the fact that the `List<Bool>` is inserting a new record every time, while the `bool[]` and `BitArray` are initialized to `false` on every record, and I only updated them where the value should be `true`, the `List<bool>` comes out tops, consistently, even including the `.ToArray()` call.

Yet another case where practical application is better than textbook knowledge, it seems... :)

Comment: It'd be interesting to know why your results contradict paul's (the array was fastest for him). But usually if one way is marginally faster on your machine, and the other way is marginally faster on someone else's machine, the answer is "it's not worth my time to figure out what's going on here" ;-)